# Do not copy XML documentation files from NuGet packages into bin

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget, xml-documentation

I can't seem to find a way to prevent XML documentation files from NuGet packages (such as Dapper for example) from being copied into bin folder. I'm using VS2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add these node in your `xxx.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>Dapper.xml</AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Then**, clean your project and then build your project.

**After that**, you will not see `Dapper.xml` file in your `bin` folder.

===========================================

**Update 1**

The above solution will prevent all such suffix files not being copied into output folder.

**Since** you do not want to prevent all such suffix files in the output folder and just want only one file not to be copied into `bin` folder, you can try this:

```
<Target Name="RemoveFilesAfterBuild" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
        <ItemGroup>
            <XMLFilesToDelete Include="$(TargetDir)\Dapper.xml"/>           
        </ItemGroup>
        <Delete Files="@(XMLFilesToDelete)" />      
</Target>
```

Comment: Wierd result: after adding those lines, XML's for all packages dissapeared, not just for Dapper. This is exactly what I need, but I'm curios why this is happening?

Comment: Sorry for not noticing that. This node will prevent all such `xml` suffix file in the `bin` folder. If you want only such one file, you should try my updated solution.